# What are the possible quest rewards from the civil war storyline?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Im trying to decide between joining the Stormcloaks or the Imperials. I intend to decide based off the potential rewards from each side.

What are the possible rewards for completing either the Stormcloak or Imperial side of the civil war quest chain?

Comment: why downvote i have searcheD EVERYWERE

Comment: I down-voted because it is very easy to find this out. Ill be posting an answer shortly

Comment: If you've searched everywhere, I'm quite sure you'd already have found this information.

Comment: took me all of 5 minutes to find, once I got around to it. Since your asking for an answer, it will take a bit longer to post one.

Comment: @Timelord64 Took 5 minutes to find, yet it's impossible to copy and paste?

Comment: @Studoku, I tend to downvote direct copy and pastes. A wiki has a different contextual format then the arqade. I'm either going to put it all in a form I'm happy with, or I'm not going to at all.

Answer (score 3):

## The Rewards

The rewards are mostly entirely balanced. Almost all quest rewards are listed as leveled rewards, either in the form of gold, or as armor and weapons. When the reward is leveled, the game determines an appropriate reward based off your current level. Faction side does not appear to make a difference.

There are several quests, however, that do offer distinctly different rewards. Ultimately, you will be choosing between faction armor, player houses, and titles. The titles are unique to each side, but both sides share the same basic structure. While certain quests reward the ability to purchase player housing, both houses are available to both sides, regardless.

As confirmed be several sources, including on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/36gi51/what_are_the_benefits_of_joining_the_stormcloaks/), [Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2657616) and on [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61489376), the biggest difference between joining one faction or the other is mostly story-based. It is quite likely that Bethesda intended the faction choice to be made based off the story path the player was wishing to take, alone, and thus deliberately set both sides up to be fairly symmetrical.

### [The Imperial Legion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Imperial_Legion)

- [Imperial Armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Imperial_Armor)
- Player housing [Hjerim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hjerim) in [Windhelm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Windhelm)

#### Imperial Titles

- Auxiliary
- Quaestor
- Praefect
- Tribune
- Legate

#### Quests

- [Joining the Legion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Joining_the_Legion)
- [The Jagged Crown](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Jagged_Crown_%28Imperial%29)
- [Message to Whiterun](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Message_to_Whiterun_%28Imperial%29)
- [Battle for Whiterun](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Whiterun_%28Imperial%29)
- [Reunification of Skyrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Reunification_of_Skyrim)

  - [A False Front](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_False_Front_%28Imperial%29)
  - [The Battle for Fort Dunstad](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Dunstad_%28Imperial%29)
  - [Compelling Tribute](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Compelling_Tribute_%28Imperial%29)
  - [The Battle for Fort Greenwall](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Compelling_Tribute_%28Imperial%29)
  - [The Battle for Fort Sungard](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Sungard_%28Imperial%29)
  - [Rescue from Fort Kastav](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Rescue_from_Fort_Kastav)
  - [The Battle for Fort Snowhawk](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Snowhawk_%28Imperial%29)
  - [The Battle for Fort Neugrad](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Neugrad)
  - [The Battle for Fort Amol](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Windhelm)
  - [The Battle for Windhelm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Windhelm)

### [The Stormcloaks](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stormcloaks)

- [Stormcloak Armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stormcloak_Officer_Armor)
- Player housing [Hjerim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hjerim) in [Windhelm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Windhelm)

#### Stormcloak Titles

- Unblooded
- Ice-Veins
- Bone-Breaker
- Snow-Hammer
- Stormblade

#### Quests

- [Joining the Stormcloaks](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Joining_the_Stormcloaks)
- [The Jagged Crown](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Jagged_Crown_(Stormcloaks))
- [Message to Whiterun](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Message_to_Whiterun_(Stormcloaks))
- [Battle for Whiterun](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Whiterun_(Stormcloaks))
- [Liberation of Skyrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Liberation_of_Skyrim)

  - [Rescue from Fort Neugrad](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Rescue_from_Fort_Neugrad)
  - [Compelling Tribute](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Compelling_Tribute_(Stormcloaks))
  - [The Battle for Fort Sungard](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Sungard_(Stormcloaks))
  - [A False Front](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_False_Front_(Stormcloaks))
  - [The Battle for Fort Snowhawk](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Snowhawk_(Stormcloaks))
  - [The Battle for Fort Dunstad](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Dunstad_(Stormcloaks))
  - [The Battle for Fort Greenwall](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Greenwall_(Stormcloaks))
  - [The Battle for Fort Kastav](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Kastav)
  - [The Battle for Fort Hraggstad](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Hraggstad)
  - [Battle for Solitude](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Solitude)

Comment: Nice formatting. +1 xD

Comment: I mean like weapons

Comment: As I said, you are rewarded weapons, but reward is based off your level, not which side your with. I could post weapons users have reported recieving for the imperials, and someone else would recieve it from the stormcloaks. Likewise, theres every chance you wont get the same weapon from the same quest, making the information useless for comparison. Honestly, the reported weapons is only in the discussion part, for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

Joining the empire will let you kill and dead thrall Ulfric, he retains his voice clip AND he uses shouts. 
Although he can only be thralled if the player is lvl 34 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

### Imperials

If you joined the Imperial, you will be able to kill Ulfric. You can take his robes which isn't very special.

### Stormcloaks

After killing General Tullius, search his body and you'll find his armor. It's the only piece of heavy armor with the lowest stats.

### Both Sides

You can't join both sides, bu they have one reward. You will be able to get the Windhelm house after you complete the questline and Blood on the Ice which start at the graveyard where a body, 3 witnesses, and a guard stands. Do the quest and you can buy Hjerim and it's furniture.

Comment: both houses can be unlocked on either side, they just make a particular house easier then the other.

Comment: That's right, it's the only way you get the house Hjerim by doing the Civil War questline and Blood On The Ice.