# Should I join the Imperial legion, or join the Stormcloak Rebellion? And can I switch?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I found out in Skyrim that you get to join 2 sides, but not both, which are the Imperials and the Stormcloaks. The problem is, I don't know which side I want to join! I don't know which side has the right to take over the providence! If I found out I joined the wrong side, can I switch? I'm going to do the Civil War quests after I completed the Main questline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I switch sides in the Civil War?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39771/how-do-i-switch-sides-in-the-civil-war)

Comment: I don't get this. Why is my question put on hold? What opinons did I put?

Comment: Which side you take is entirely up to you; we can't make that choice for you.  What we *can* do, though, is tell you what each side will do, so you can make an informed choice on your own.  Don't ask us what you should do; ask us what impact the choices have.

Comment: @Frank okay it's edited is that okay? Or do I have to edit some more?

Comment: @Jim After the edit it's a duplicate of the question galacticninja linked.

Comment: It looks to be less opinionated now, but it's also a duplicate; see [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238510/what-are-the-possible-quest-rewards-from-the-civil-war-storyline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you choose a side, that's it, no switching. The rewards are mostly the same, except for whichever leader you kill, you get to loot.

The Stormcloaks are a bunch of racist Nords who want to make Skyrim for Nords and only Nords. If they win, they'll probably eject non-Nordic humans from the province, and murder everyone else(after the game, nothing happens during). Also, Ulfric is either an active Thalmor agent, or is "merely" compromised in someway.

The Imperials are the sad remnant of a once powerful, centuries old Empire. They are trying against all odds to hold their vision of Tamriel together, but after losing a war to the Thalmor (who are essentially fantasy Nazi elves), the provinces are crumbling. Skyrim is one of the most stable, and therefore most profitable still remaining. Their interests lie in Cyrodill first, and they will gladly exploit Skyrim for everything it's worth to keep the Empire lurching on for a few more decades.

Comment: You certainly *can* switch allegiance during the civil war.

Comment: @JonK I guess you meant http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39771/how-do-i-switch-sides-in-the-civil-war?lq\ ?

Comment: tl;dr there are pros and cons for both sides

Comment: I've also noticed that as you increase the status of the Thieves Guild, the various Patrons & Fences you meet are generally supporters of the Empire.  One imagines that a stable political/power structure is good for "Business".

Comment: Okay, but you're not telling me which side is better are you?

Comment: @jim I am not. IMNSHO, the Imperials are the lesser evil, but you need to make the decision for yourself

Comment: Okay, this question is answered. I'm going with the Imperials.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, but what about the Thalmor? Are they more evil than the Imperials and Stormcloaks since they banned the Talos Worship? That made the Nords made since Talos is their Nord God right? I'll still let this answer accepted alright?

Comment: And hey! Why did you reject my edit? There is a way to switch you know! Go to **How do I switch sides in the Civil War?**.